# JBoss Drools - how to get data (facts) from java to DRL

Tags: jboss, drools

How can I get fact definied by user in GUI and insert it to DRL?

**For example: The user has chosen black car in GUI (JavaFX), and now I want to use that fact in DRL code. How to send that info about black car to DRL? Should i  use POJO?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to execute rules that you have written in DRL file you have to create a POJO and using `KieSession` you can execute your rules. For example,

```
val pojo = new POJO('POJO arguments') 
val kieServices = KieServices.Factory.get()
val kieContainer = kieServices.newKieClasspathContainer()
val kieSession = kContainer.newKieSession()
kieSession.insert(pojo)
kieSession.fireAllRules()
```

Read [this](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.5.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/#KIEChapter) documentation. You can get all the drool-API examples [here](https://github.com/kiegroup/drools/tree/6.0.x/drools-examples-api)